# Show Time drift relative to a time Server

Tags: time, ntp, date

I want to monitor the time drift on my workstation. How can I compare my local time to a timeserver like pool.ntp.org and show the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Old, Outdated Answer**

If you run `ntpdate -q pool.ntp.org`, it will show you the difference between your time and the time server.

**strong text**

`ntpdate` has been deprecated for quite some time, and as of this edit (2017) it may no longer be available on new distributions.

`clockdiff _server_` will show the clock difference and has been available since 12.04 LTS.  See the [man page for clockdiff](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/clockdiff.8.html).

Comment: This doesn't work on all Linux systems - I have an embedded computer running Debian GNU/Linux 3.1, kernel 2.6.21-ts for which `ntpdate` is a shell script that gives the following for the above command: `Usage: /etc/init.d/ntpdate {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload}`.  Any alternatives?

Comment: @RogerDueck According to the question [ntpd vs nptdate -
 pros and cons](https://askubuntu.com/q/297560/4435), `ntpdate` has been deprecated for quite a while.  The suggestion is to use `ntpd` instead.

Comment: My system doesn't have `clockdiff` either, and I don't see any way to make `ntpd` give the one-time clock difference that the deprecated `ntpdate` did.