# ntpdate: no server suitable for synchronization found

Tags: time, ntp

**My clock is off**, so I would like to synchronize it using `ntpdate`. I tried several different NTP servers, but for some reason I always get the following error message:

```
$ sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
4 Mar 12:27:35 ntpdate[1258]: no server suitable for synchronization found
$ sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org
4 Mar 12:27:50 ntpdate[1267]: no server suitable for synchronization found
$ sudo ntpdate de.pool.ntp.org
4 Mar 12:28:01 ntpdate[1273]: no server suitable for synchronization found
$ sudo ntpdate us.pool.ntp.org
4 Mar 12:28:12 ntpdate[1276]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

## Related questions

I have looked through **related questions**, but none solve my problem:

- [Unable to synchronize time using NTP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244526/unable-to-synchronize-time-using-ntp) - this guy gets a different error than I; his problem was a conflict with the `ntpd` daemon. I do not have the `ntp` package (which includes the `ntpd` daemon) installed at all.
- [How to force a clock update using ntp?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254826/how-to-force-a-clock-update-using-ntp) - this guy's problem is that the `ntpdate` command wouldn't properly work at boot time when he put it into his `/etc/rc.local`, and the problem was similarly a conflict with the `ntpd` daemon that was running. Neither am I trying to run `ntpdate` at boot time, nor (again) do I have the `ntpd` daemon installed.
- [Unable to sync time using `ntpdate`, error: "no server suitable for synchronization found"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49401/unable-to-sync-time-using-ntpdate-error-no-server-suitable-for-synchronizat) - this is my error alright, but the accepted answer is basically "Use `ntpd` instead of `ntpdate`". Aaarggh...

## Things I have tried

### I installed the ntp package

...and tried using the `ntpd` daemon instead of the `ntpdate` utility. It won't sync my time either; the daemon starts fine, but my clock remains off. I even tried using the exact `/etc/ntp.conf` from the accepted answer in the latter post, and restarting the daemon. No go. Anyway, I don't want to use the daemon. I am perfectly aware that `ntpdate` is considered "deprecated", and it is advised to use `ntpd -q` instead. Also see here:

- [ntpd vs ntpdate: pros and cons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297560/ntpd-vs-ntpdate-pros-and-cons)

But since `ntpd` doesn't work for me either, *the problem lies elsewhere*. And I find that I would prefer not having to install any extra packages just for synchronizing the clock. `ntpdate` comes pre-installed with Ubuntu, and *it should work just fine*. So I uninstalled the `ntp` package again.

### Maybe port 123 is blocked?

From this post:

- ["no server suitable for synchronization found" error when trying to run `ntpdate`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180876/no-server-suitable-for-synchronization-found-error-when-trying-to-run-ntpdate)

...I got the idea that port 123 may be blocked from my computer / network at my work place. Indeed,

```
$ sudo nmap -p123 -sU -P0 localhost
...
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
123/udp closed ntp 
...
$ sudo ufw allow 123/udp
Rules updated
Rules updated (v6)
$ sudo nmap -p123 -sU -P0 localhost
...
PORT    STATE SERVICE
123/udp open  ntp
...
```

But still:

```
$ sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
4 Mar 13:06:16 ntpdate[4361]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

Even with the `-u` option, which tells `ntpdate` to use an unprivileged port for syncing (instead of port `123`) which is certainly not blocked from my work place:

```
$ sudo ntpdate -u ntp.ubuntu.com
4 Mar 13:06:28 ntpdate[4427]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

### Maybe the strata are too high?

Lastly, from this post over at serverfault:

- [ntpdate -d Server dropped Strata too high](https://serverfault.com/questions/277375/ntpdate-d-server-dropped-strata-too-high)

...I thought that maybe the strata from the NTP servers are too high. They aren't, though. Let's see a little more debugging info:

```
$ sudo ntpdate -dv ntp.ubuntu.com
 4 Mar 13:12:24 ntpdate[4523]: ntpdate 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Wed Oct  9 19:08:07 UTC 2013 (1)
Looking for host ntp.ubuntu.com and service ntp
host found : golem.canonical.com
transmit(91.189.89.199)
transmit(91.189.94.4)
transmit(91.189.89.199)
transmit(91.189.94.4)
transmit(91.189.89.199)
transmit(91.189.94.4)
transmit(91.189.89.199)
transmit(91.189.94.4)
transmit(91.189.89.199)
transmit(91.189.94.4)
91.189.89.199: Server dropped: no data
91.189.94.4: Server dropped: no data
server 91.189.89.199, port 123
stratum 0, precision 0, leap 00, trust 000
refid [91.189.89.199], delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    00000000.00000000  Mon, Jan  1 1900  1:00:00.000
originate timestamp: 00000000.00000000  Mon, Jan  1 1900  1:00:00.000
transmit timestamp:  d6c041ae.e6166441  Tue, Mar  4 2014 13:12:30.898
filter delay:  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
filter offset: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
offset 0.000000

server 91.189.94.4, port 123
stratum 0, precision 0, leap 00, trust 000
refid [91.189.94.4], delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    00000000.00000000  Mon, Jan  1 1900  1:00:00.000
originate timestamp: 00000000.00000000  Mon, Jan  1 1900  1:00:00.000
transmit timestamp:  d6c041af.1948fc50  Tue, Mar  4 2014 13:12:31.098
filter delay:  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
filter offset: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
offset 0.000000

 4 Mar 13:12:33 ntpdate[4523]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

Pfeeewww... this was a long one, sorry for that. I'm stumped. Any clues?

## Update: additional infos

No matter whether an NTP server `HOSTNAME` figures in `/etc/ntp.conf`, and no matter whether the `ntpd` service is running or not, whenever I run `sudo ntpdate -u HOSTNAME`, I get `no server suitable for synchronization found`. Same thing when the `ntpd` service is *not* running and I *omit* the `-u` option. When the `ntpd` service *is* running and I omit the `-u` option, I instead get `the NTP socket is in use, exiting`.

Also:

```
$ timedatectl status
      Local time: Wed 2014-03-05 13:11:54 CET
  Universal time: Wed 2014-03-05 12:11:54 UTC
        Timezone: Europe/Berlin (CET, +0100)
     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: no
 Last DST change: DST ended at
                  Sun 2013-10-27 02:59:59 CEST
                  Sun 2013-10-27 02:00:00 CET
 Next DST change: DST begins (the clock jumps one hour forward) at
                  Sun 2014-03-30 01:59:59 CET
                  Sun 2014-03-30 03:00:00 CEST
```

**But the UTC time is not correct here.** Right now UTC time is `11:11`, not `12:11`.

And:

```
$ sudo hwclock --show
Wed 05 Mar 2014 01:11:56 PM CET  -0.625627 seconds
```

Comment: you said you ran ` sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com` but did you do that after adding  `ntp.ubuntu.com` to `/etc/ntp.conf` s server field? If not see the following answer

Comment: try `sudo ntpdate 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org

Comment: Hi, see my comment to your answer. I tried adding `server pool.ntp.org` to `/etc/ntp.conf`, but `ntpdate -u pool.ntp.org` throws the same error. I also tried this with `ntp.ubuntu.com` (adding it to `/etc/ntp.conf`, re-starting the `ntp` service, re-running `ntpdate -u` on the exact server I just added to `/etc/ntp.conf`). Summing up, **it does not matter if the server I'm trying to sync with is mentioned in `/etc/ntp.conf`**. I get the `no server suitable...` error in all cases (except when the `ntp` service is running *and* I omit the `-u` option, then I get the `NTP socket in use` error).

Comment: Ok, I also tried `sudo ntpdate 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org`, which is already in the `/etc/ntp.conf` file. No luck - same error.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Your hosting provider is blocking ntp packets. This heavy handed approach has been implemented by some ISPs in response to the DDoS attacks. You can see that ntpdate is sending the packets fron the ntpdate -vd :

```
transmit(91.189.94.4)
transmit(91.189.89.199)
transmit(91.189.94.4)
transmit(91.189.89.199)
```

I would contact your ISP and ask if they are blocking external ntp requests and if they have a local server that you can use for time sync.

There are a couple more obscure possibilities but it is tough to rule them out since you have not posted any logs from syslog.

Comment: You are perfectly right. It seems our university is blocking external NTP requests. It also offers a few local NTP servers as an alternative. These work perfectly. I see now that the output of `ntpdate -dv` should also include some `receive(...)` and not only `transmit(...)` messages. ;) Many thanks!

Comment: One question though, how can the university block NTP packets when I use `ntpdate` with the `-u` option? Since this uses an unprivileged port instead of port 123, it means that their firewall rules must be more complex than simply "block incoming packets on port 123". So do they do some kind of deep packet inspection, then?

Comment: They will have one firewall rule that says "Block all traffic with a destination port of 123" and then a couple of exceptions for their ntp hosts

Comment: I had this same problem. I was able to resolve it by doing a traceroute outbound and I found a local server on the route that I was able to sync to that was running ntp. One of them was blocking it though. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: For me, `ntpdate -vd` says `no servers can be used, exiting`.

Comment: @highbandwidth are you able to resolve the NTP server names to IP addresses? And if so do you know they are serving time and reachable?

Comment: @dfc, I figured it out. I had ntpd installed and loaded. That's why ntpdate -vd didn't work.

Comment: This was my problem: AT&T Uverse is blocking Port 123 in both directions: https://www.att.com/gen/public-affairs?pid=20879 (as of Feb 1, 2016) My fix was using `ntpdate -u` which uses an unprivileged (and unblocked) port.

Comment: spot on , I disconnected from current network and connected to 4G and it worked. Thanks dfc.

Comment: Seems like this might be a common case with university networks. You may try to use `ntp.example-university.com`. (It worked for me here at the Aalto university in Finland.)

Comment: I was struggling with this for days. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 69):

This is not an ntp answer, however...

```
sudo date -s "$(wget -qSO- --max-redirect=0 google.com 2>&1 | grep Date: | cut -d' ' -f5-8)Z"
```

this and the curl version [here](https://superuser.com/questions/307158/how-to-use-ntpdate-behind-a-proxy).

Comment: This is terrible, but it works.

Comment: Feeding unsanitized data to bash command run as root? Awesome thanks for playing. This answer should be downvoted with extreme prejudice.

Comment: Much less painful than having to deal with ISP support. Also, not critical at all if run in a local VM for test purposes.

Comment: Can you explain me what it is doing ?

Comment: @SurajJain Many web-servers return `Date` header. In that command date -s for set date, wget -S for store all headers, 2>&1 for logging errors in stdout, grep for pick line with header Date, cut for strip day of week and GMT. Z at end for treat date as UTC. Accuracy will depends of network speed.

Comment: This works for a quick fix. For a more secure (I think!) solution at work for test VMs that could not access NTP, I made a cron job for a PHP script that would the header of a site (like Google, for instance) via [get_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) and sanitize and re-format the date using [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and date, and set it via [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Answer (score 30):

**Use htpdate**

If ntp transmission is blocked in your network, install htpdate. It syncs time over http protocol. Accuracy will be withing 0.5 secs, according to man page.

```
sudo apt-get install htpdate
sudo htpdate -a google.com
```

htpdate service will start when you install the package. Time will be update immediately if there is internet connection.

Comment: Please don't just copy and paste the same answer in every topic you find about ntp.

Comment: Copypasta or not, this solution worked for me while I was receiving the `ntpdate[22109]: no server suitable for synchronization found` error.

Comment: in Athens,Greece feb 2021 on vodafone, only htpdate worked! thanks!!! I cannot tell how safe it is, but nothing else worked for me. Seems the ISP (Vodafone) blocks the ntp since all goes Ok but "ntp service is in use" and "no server suitable for synchronization" .., was all i was getting. Saved me from at least 30' talking to isp auto-answering etc.

Comment: Great solution - thanks for posting! Worked for me when network prevented NTP updates ($ ntpdate -u <IP>).

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue and this is how I solved it.
I have give a detailed answer from top to bottom. You might want to skip to middle of my answer or just refer the screenshots below for understanding it in a glance.

**First** install ntpdate(Obviously you have done this)

```
sudo apt-get install ntpdate
```

**NEXT** You need to configure ntp with servers as follows:

You should at least set following parameter in /etc/ntp.conf config file:
`server`

For example, open /etc/ntp.conf file using nano text editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/ntp.conf
```

Locate server parameter and if it is empty set it as follows:

```
server pool.ntp.org
```

But usually In ubuntu already some servers are prewritten which might be

```
server 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
server 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
server 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
server 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
```

[image]

**Then Save the file and restart the ntpd service**:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ntpd start
```

You can synchronize the system clock to an NTP server immediately with following command:

```
sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

or just run already servers are defined

```
sudo ntpdate 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
```

or other servers that are defined using server

generally

```
sudo ntpdate <one of the servername in /etc/ntp.conf>
```

**BUT** after that there is a chance you get the Error `NTP socket in use` as shown below:

[image]

In that case just run

```
ntpdate -u pool.ntp.org
```

to update when ntp deamon is running

OR just stop the deamon,update and start it again as follows:

```
sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org
sudo service ntp stop
sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org
sudo service ntp start
```

and you will get

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your detailed answer! Unfortunately it did not work for me. I have the `/etc/ntp.conf` that came along with Ubuntu, never made any changes to it. I pasted it here: http://pastebin.com/bB0sskzv. I **also** tried adding `server pool.ntp.org` at the top of the server list, as shown in you screenshot. Find that here: http://pastebin.com/YH372Jdi. **With both of these setups**, I ran the sequence of commands that you proposed: I added a screenshot to my original post. The result was exactly the same with both the unmodified and the modified `/etc/ntp.conf`. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: what does `timedatectl status` return

Comment: See output of the `timedatectl status` command in my original post.

Comment: I have now tried with all 4 predefined servers (namely, `{0..3}.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org`), both with and without `-u` option. Always the same error.

Comment: just tell me this one also. output of `sudo hwclock --show`

Comment: I added the output of `sudo hwclock --show` for completeness, but actually, dfc's answer solved my problem. Anyway, I thank you also. :)

Comment: This command did it for me `sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org`

Answer (score 6):

Similar to Alex's answer, this worked for me for getting around the ntp port being firewalled:

```
sudo date -s "$(curl http://s3.amazonaws.com -v 2>&1 | \
  grep "Date: " | awk '{ print $3 " " $5 " " $4 " " $7 " " $6 " GMT"}')"
```